# What is interrupt 69 in x86 16-bit assembly language?

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, x86, x86-16

I was looking at some snippet and saw these lines (part of the `.com` file):

```
  DB 66; 
  CALL D59C:C2C0; 
  INT 69
  MOV SI, C8C6
```

What does `INT 69` do?

I didn't find anything online, and I didn't find anything here as well:

The weird thing is that there is no moving any value to `AH` or `AL` before the `INT 69`.

*[EMU8086. 8086 microprocessor emulator. Integrated disassembler.](http://www.emu8086.com/assembler_tutorial/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html)*

Comment: It is OS defined. We can't answer this without knowing what operating system it is for.

Comment: Unless you're doing something deeply exotic, running 16 bit code on Windows XP actually runs it inside a DOS emulator. So you want to go look up DOS references --- see Bob Kaufman's answer of Ralf Brown's Interrupt List, which is *the* reference for this stuff. (Although note that Windows XP itself uses `int 0x2e` for its own purposes.)

Comment: INT 69 is 45h. That wasn't a standard interrupt on the PC or MS-DOS. What does this program do? Does it install its own handler for INT 69?

Comment: Also, that's 69 in hex, not decimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that everything is in hex here, if this is 16-bit code then we have:

```
66                         DB 66
9A C0 C2 9C D5             CALL D59C:C2C0
CD 69                      INT 69
BE C6 C8                   MOV SI, C8C6
```

But `0x66` is the operand size override prefix (presumably just not disassembled properly here), which (in 16-bit code) causes the following instruction to take a 32-bit operand instead of a 16-bit one.  So this code is actually:

```
66 9A C0 C2 9C D5 CD 69    CALL 69CD:D59CC2C0
BE C6 C8                   MOV SI, C8C6
```

A far call to a fairly random-looking 16:32 bit absolute address from 16-bit code doesn't look very plausible to me.

So I would guess that this is actually data, rather than code...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the given code is meant to execute in 16-bit mode and encodes consecutive instructions, I have a different interpretation of it.

`DB 66` is the `operand size prefix`. In 16-bit mode it tells the CPU to interpret instruction operands as 32-bit instead of 16-bit. So, the `CALL` instruction will be interpreted as `CALL 16-bit selector:32-bit offset` instead of `CALL 16-bit selector:16-bit offset`. The "missing" 2 bytes of the address are the `INT 69` "instruction".

The effective code is then this:

```
CALL 69CD:D59CC2C0
MOV SI, C8C6
```

But that doesn't make much sense to me because a call with such an address (offset > 0FFFFh) will cause an exception. What kind of code is that?

Answer (score 2):

A search for x86 interrupts yielded [this list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm), presumably written by one Ralf Brown. If it's what I believe it is, this is the definitive list of interrupts from a generation ago. Brings back memories.